# Database for structured output learning

Tags: classification, structured-data, svm

I'm new at this so please be gentle.

I'm currently trying to apply some structured prediction algorithms using kernel methods. The thing I'm missing is a good database for which to test this on. I've currently searched (and continuing to search) for some free database, but found nothing (useful) until now.

Just so I make it more clear what I'm on about you can look at this paper as a reference:

http://www-kd.iai.uni-bonn.de/pubattachments/402/GaertnerV09ECML.pdf

Currently I'm searching for databases on this link and I will update this topic if I find something suitable:
http://www.quora.com/Data/Where-can-I-get-large-datasets-open-to-the-public?q=large+datase

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good collection of decent-sized datasets, try the World Bank's Databank:
http://data.worldbank.org/

There are enough data variables and pre-compiled datasets that you should be able to find something for data mining/prediction algorithms. Also, these datasets cover about 40 years - this means that you can cross-compare timespans or decades, in case you want to take that approach for your prediction building.